# Take number from user. For example if user enter 123 then it will print abc if user enter 13 12 11 then output would be mlk using python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, ascii, user-input

Take number from user. For example if user enter 123 then it will print abc if user enter numbers 13  12  11  then output would be 'mlk'  using python language.

Please ! Help me to solve out this question.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
         'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

for i in enumerate((list1)):
    inputnum = int(input("enter number"))
    print(i)


Output  would be:
  (0, 'a')
(1, 'b')
(2, 'c')
(3, 'd')
(4, 'e')
(5, 'f')
(6, 'g')
(7, 'h')
(8, 'i')
(9, 'j')
(10, 'k')
(11, 'l')
(12, 'm')
(13, 'n')
(14, 'o')
(15, 'p')
(16, 'q')
(17, 'r')
(18, 's')
(19, 't')
(20, 'u')
(21, 'v')
(22, 'w')
(23, 'x')
(24, 'y')
(25, 'z')
```

expected:
**If User enter 234 it will print cde as output**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a lazy homework question.   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: you can create a dictionary.

Comment: You need to think more about what the input should look like. For example, if the input is '13' then is that 'ac' or 'm'?

Comment: Thanks for your suggession.If user enter 13 then it will print m  not ac.

Comment: @mx0 the appropriate close reason is "Needs More Focus". Since questions exist to be part of the site rather than to help OP, we don't actually care that much about OP's motives; but we do care about effort put into properly defining a specific question that is about one thing. Homework questions are inherently not about one thing, because the goal is to exercise the student's problem-solving skills by having them put things together.

Comment: @user21070980 If 13=='m' then why is 234=='cde'? That makes no sense

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can store user input as a list. and create a dictionary

```
usr_input=list(map(int,input("Enter the number:").split())) #User input stored as a list by using mapping

dic={1:'a', 2:'b', 3:'c', 4:'d', 5:'e', 6:'f', 7:'g', 8:'h', 9:'i', 10:'j', 11:'k', 12:'l',13:'m', 14:'n', 15:'o', 16:'p', 17:'q', 18:'r', 19:'s', 20:'t', 21:'u', 22:'v', 23:'w', 24:'x', 25:'y', 26:'z'}

res=""
for num in usr_input:
    res+=dic.get(num,'') #If the value is not present in a dictionary than add empty string to the res

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the number:11 13 27 23
kmw

As 11:'k', 13:'m', 27:'' [as an empty string], 23:'w' -> 'k'+'m'+''+'w' ->'kmw'
```

Let's say you want to optimize **space complexity** [i.e without dictionary].

```
usr_input=list(map(int,input("Enter the number:").split()))

res=""
for num in usr_input:
    if 97<=num+96<=122: #ascii values of 'a':97 'z':122
        res+=chr(num+96)

print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the number:11 13 27 16
kmp
```

Comment: **Hint** It's not a good idea to change the asker use case. You should be able to work on it without changing the asker's original data.  For example I could see that you change the original list to  `dict` to suit your code. Suggesting that the asker should use a dictionary. You should rather maintain the provided list then convert it to a dict. **e,g:** `list_dict = {index+1: l for index, l in enumerate(list1)}` now you work with `list_dict`

Comment: thanks for the feedback..just also wanted to clarify he writes if user enter 123 then it will print `abc` `13 12 11` then output would be `'mlk'` just can't predict how i can do this.. @JamiuS.

Comment: can i assume he was trying to say `1 2 3`?? .. @JamiuS.

Answer (score -1):

If the input is a string of digits then the output will never include letters beyond *j* in the alphabet.

Therefore:

```
while user_input := input('Enter a number: '):
    print(''.join(['abcdefghij'[i] for i in map(int, user_input)]))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter a number: 234
cde
```

Comment: so in your case 1 will map to b instead of a, which is not what the OP wants

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki Quote from the question "234 it will print cde" Therefore 1=='b'

Answer (score -2):

Based on using an `input()`, I can suggest a following solution.

```py
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l',
         'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


inputnum_list = []
while True:
    value_given = input("enter number")
    if value_given == '':
        output = [list1[letter_position] for letter_position in inputnum_list]
        print(''.join(output))
        inputnum_list = []
        continue
    inputnum_list.append(int(value_given))
```

It will take string inputs punctuated by "enter" presses and will output a list of letters after a blank value is entered.

Comment: your function tends to infinite loop. instead of `continue` you should apply `break`

Comment: @YashMehta but this loop would be canonical for something like codewars, where code is expected to accept many lines of text and respond with prints multiple times

Comment: yes you are correct.. but the testcase he shared is not in multi lines.. it is in the same line @Kirill Setdekov